# Get custom post type REST API not working

Tags: custom-post-types, php, rest-api

I want to load the content of a modal using the REST API of wordpress. I've added the `show_in_rest` param to the custom post type I've registered in my function file, but I'm unable to load it, I will get this error `rest_no_route`. 
How I can fix this?

Functions:

```
function staff()
  {
    $labels = array(
      'name'               => _x( 'Team', 'post type general name'),
      'singular_name'      => _x( 'Team', 'post type singular name'),
      'menu_name'          => _x( 'Team', 'admin menu'),
      'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Team', 'add new on admin bar'),
      'add_new'            => _x( 'Nuova Persona', 'Aggiungi membro team'),
      'add_new_item'       => __( 'Name'),
      'new_item'           => __( 'Aggiungi Persona'),
      'edit_item'          => __( 'Modifica Persona'),
      'view_item'          => __( 'Visualizza Team'),
      'all_items'          => __( 'Visualizza Tutti'),
      'featured_image'     => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
      'search_items'       => __( 'Cerca Persona'),
      'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent:'),
      'not_found'          => __( 'No member found.'),
      'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No member found in Trash.'),
    );

    $args = array(
      'labels'             => $labels,
      #'menu_icon'       => 'dashicons-star-half',
      'description'        => __( 'Description.'),
      'public'             => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui'            => true,
      'show_in_menu'       => true,
      'show_in_rest'       => true,
      'query_var'          => true,
      'rewrite'            => true,
      'capability_type'    => 'post',
      'has_archive'        => true,
      'hierarchical'       => true,
      'menu_position'      => null,
      'supports'           => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields')
    );

    register_post_type( 'staff', $args );
  }
  add_action('init', 'staff');
```

JS/AJAX code:

```
  $('.staff-link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    console.log(id);
    $.getJSON('https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/'+type+'&id='+id, function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Two things to try: `unregister_post_type('staff')` just before your registration code, and visit the Settings > Permalinks page. Sometimes settings persist until you unregister and re-register, and sometimes they persist until you flush rewrite rules, which just visiting the Permalinks page without making changes does.

Comment: I'm able to get the post type now, but how I can get only a particular post by id? I'm passing the `?id=` param but this isn't working

Comment: try to call `wp-json/wp/v2/staff/1234` to have 1 object.

Comment: @Kaperto worked fine, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution for those who would like to forget the WordPress REST API.

Create your own PHP file where you will return a JSON code of the desired data. Basic structure of the file:

(Note: you need to init your file by including your file in functions.php and the add_action "init")

```
<?php
$autorisation = isset($_POST['activate']) ? $_POST['activate'] : '';
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

if($autorisation !== 'call-staff-post'){
    return;
}

if(empty($id)){
    // If id empty, return all data
    $args = array('post_type' => 'staff', 'posts_per_page' => '-1');
} else {
    $args = array('post_type' => 'staff', 'p' => $id);
}

$staff = new WP_Query($args);

$return = array();
while($staff->have_posts()) : $staff->the_post();
    $return[] = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
    );
endwhile;

echo json_encode($return);

exit;
?>
```

Your JS/POST call:

```
$.post(window.location.href, {
    activate: 'call-staff-post',
    id: YOUR ID // Need to be integer not a string
}, function(data){
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(json);
});
```

Comment: Nice solution, but the REST API will do the same job in a more wordpress compilant way!

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain me how it's a more compilant way? Or maybe you'll say "compliant" ? For the first way I do not agree.