# How to reload a php script, using AJAX and jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Good evening, im a beginner in WordPress and i'd like some advices.
I have a php script that load some articles thumbnails randomly according to some parameters.

```
<div id="logos  " class="slide colonne">
<?php
$posts = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
     'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ),
)
);
$query = new WP_Query($posts);
while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php echo '<div class="colonne"><a href="' . get_permalink( $_post->ID ) . '" target="_blank" title="' . esc_attr( $_post->post_title ) . '">';
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $_post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
echo '</a></div>'; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

It is located in wp-content\themes\*childtheme*\parts\logos.php
and loaded in my footer.php

```
<?php get_template_part('parts/logos'); ?>
```

The result is working pretty well but now, i'd like it to autorefresh each x seconds.
So i've looked for a method to do it and i've come upon this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440723/wordpress-auto-refresh-specific-div
And thus here is my script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var refresh = function(){
  $("#logos").fadeOut("slow").load("/wp-content/themes/capitaine/parts/logos.php").fadeIn("slow");

}
setInterval(refresh, 3000 );  ///////// 30 seconds
 });
```

I've included it in my functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery',
        'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js',
        false,
        '3.3.1',
        true
    );
wp_enqueue_script(
    'refresh',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    '1.0',
    true
);
```

But then i was getting this error

[image]

The only way i've found to arrange this is from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219396/need-to-run-wp-query-on-a-separate-php-file-for-an-ajax-call

I've added `<php $abs_path= __FILE__;
$get_path=explode('wp-content',$abs_path);
$path=$get_path[0].'wp-load.php';
include($path);
?>` to the top of my script and it's kinda working, but not according to the css i've defined.
So here are my questions:
Is that method good ?
If not, i would take any good advices.
And if it is ok, i would know why the  is not in adequation with the css anymore.

e.g. 
Before the reloading:
[image]After the reloading:

[image]

Thanks for yours answers and sorry for my messy english and my messy explication.

Comment: Forget your <php $abs_path=.... code.  >>> When you load an "external" script with WordPress function in the file, you need init your file by including it with add_action "init" in your functions.php

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer.
I think my external script is already included with add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name' );
My actual prob is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374145/uncaught-error-class-wp-query-not-found-in-url-wordpress

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I don't call script for talk about JS, I talk about your php code. If you call an external PHP, you need init it in your functions.php. otherwise, wp_query or other WordPress functions, will not work

Comment: Put a look here (Since you do not use the WordPress REST API to call something, I gave an example here) >>> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/353122/177503